# Python: Filtering data from Json file based on some json object?

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, lambda, filter

I have this file with Json data as shown below

```
{
  "tags": [], 
  "imageheight": 1024, 
  "imagewidth": 1920,
  "children": [
   {
    "tags": [
      "occluded>10",
      "unsure_orientation"
     ], 
    "x0": 447, 
    "y1": 479, 
    "y0": 391, 
    "x1": 475, 
    "children": [], 
    "identity": "pedestrian"
   },
   {
     "tags": [], 
     "x0": 527, 
     "y1": 477, 
     "y0": 391, 
     "x1": 551, 
     "children": [], 
     "identity": "person-group-far-away"
   }, 
   {
      "tags": [
        "occluded>10"
      ], 
     "x0": 482, 
     "children": [], 
     "y1": 508, 
     "y0": 404, 
     "x1": 513, 
     "Orient": 345.0, 
     "identity": "pedestrian"
   },
  ], 
  "identity": "frame"
}
```

I want to filter this data based on `"identity": "pedestrian"`  and `"tags": [ "occluded>10" ]`

I tried below code.

```
for key, value in json_object.items():
    if key=="children":
        json_object['children'] = (list(filter(lambda x: (x["identity"]=="pedestrian" and x["tags"] == "occluded>10"), value)))
```

But this is not working. When I tried with only **identity** value, it works fine (I can filter this data). But when I include **tag** it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x['tags'] is of type list, so if you want test that this list contains only one item `"occluded>10"`, you can compare `["occluded>10"] == x['tags']`.

For example:

```
import json

d = {
  "tags": [],
  "imageheight": 1024,
  "imagewidth": 1920,
  "children": [
   {
    "tags": [
      "occluded>10",
      "unsure_orientation"
     ],
    "x0": 447,
    "y1": 479,
    "y0": 391,
    "x1": 475,
    "children": [],
    "identity": "pedestrian"
   },
   {
     "tags": [],
     "x0": 527,
     "y1": 477,
     "y0": 391,
     "x1": 551,
     "children": [],
     "identity": "person-group-far-away"
   },
   {
      "tags": [
        "occluded>10"
      ],
     "x0": 482,
     "children": [],
     "y1": 508,
     "y0": 404,
     "x1": 513,
     "Orient": 345.0,
     "identity": "pedestrian"
   },
  ],
  "identity": "frame"
}

d['children'] = [v for v in d['children'] if v['identity'] == 'pedestrian' and ['occluded>10'] == v['tags']]

# pretty print to screen:
print( json.dumps(d, indent=4) )
```

Prints:

```
{
    "tags": [],
    "imageheight": 1024,
    "imagewidth": 1920,
    "children": [
        {
            "tags": [
                "occluded>10"
            ],
            "x0": 482,
            "children": [],
            "y1": 508,
            "y0": 404,
            "x1": 513,
            "Orient": 345.0,
            "identity": "pedestrian"
        }
    ],
    "identity": "frame"
}
```

---

EDIT: To filter items that contain tag `'occluded>10'`, you can use `any()`. For example:

```
d['children'] = [v for v in d['children'] if v['identity'] == 'pedestrian' and any('occluded>10' == t for t in v['tags'])]

# pretty print to screen:
print( json.dumps(d, indent=4) )
```

Prints:

```
{
    "tags": [],
    "imageheight": 1024,
    "imagewidth": 1920,
    "children": [
        {
            "tags": [
                "occluded>10",
                "unsure_orientation"
            ],
            "x0": 447,
            "y1": 479,
            "y0": 391,
            "x1": 475,
            "children": [],
            "identity": "pedestrian"
        },
        {
            "tags": [
                "occluded>10"
            ],
            "x0": 482,
            "children": [],
            "y1": 508,
            "y0": 404,
            "x1": 513,
            "Orient": 345.0,
            "identity": "pedestrian"
        }
    ],
    "identity": "frame"
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that it is a list and that's why I don't have an on how to filter on tags. And thanks for your answer, but I want to filter the data irrespective of the number of items in the tags filed. So in this case it should also return the object which contains two items in tags. Is there any way that could help me with this.

Comment: @keertikulkarni I updated my answer. You can use `any()` to filter items.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This solved my issue.